# getAllCellInfo() always has size 0 [Android]

Tags: android

i'm trying to get the cell info of my phone. But the function getAllCellInfo() does not have any CellInfo items in it. It's empty (size == 0).

Permissions

> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

and

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

are granted.

Code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<CellInfo> cis = tm.getAllCellInfo();
Log.i("LOG", "Size is: " +cis.size());
```

And the Log:

```
09-23 22:10:13.521 26395-26395/XXX.YYY.ZZZ I/LOG: Size is: 0
```

Device is Huawei P9 Lite. Cannot test on other phone ATM.

Anyone knows what's wrong?